# #Import directive fails with error "Request?" is not a valid C++ identifier

Tags: c++, com, typelib

I am trying to import a type library in my VC++ console application using following command.

```
#import "C:\typelib.tlb"
```

When I build the project I get following error:

**Error    C1196    'Request?': identifier found in type library 'C:\typelib.tlb' is not a valid C++ identifier**

I haven't developed this type library but on inspection I have found that some of functions in type library are using null able parameters and I assume that's what is causing the problem e.g.

```
Sub ScheduleManyWithPossibleRequest(ByVal Requester As String, ByVal Request? As Boolean, ByVal SkipUnschedulableActivities? As Boolean)
```

Is there any way I can import this type library?

Comment: Are you compiling with managed extensions enabled?

Comment: Hard to imagine what happened here, ? is a type declaration character in VB for a nullable parameter and that can't (and won't) be exported to a type library.  Actually smells like an obfuscator at work.  #import allows you to rename identifiers with the `rename` attribute.  Using a telephone is highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks hans rename worked.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to import it by using following directive with import.

```
 #import "C:\typelib.tlb" rename("Request?", "Request")
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if this would work but try doing #include instead.
Let me know if this helps, if not i'll look more into it.

Comment: You cannot `#include` a type library.  You have to use `#import`.

Comment: Remy is right I cant use #include with a type library. I can only use #include once after build a ".tlh" file is generated.